# Yii2 URL is not working

Tags: php, yii2

I have following URL rule in my configuration file:

```
        'rules' => [
            'http://<store_url:\w+>.example.com/<product_name:\w+>' => 'index/index'
        ]
```

I type http://mystore2.example.com/iphone-15 and I got 404 error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Ok, what is the correct rule then?

Comment: Did it solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, I used: http://<store_url:[a-z0-9A-Z-_]+>.example.com/<product_name:[a-z0-9A-Z-_]+>' => 'index/index

Comment: Umid Boltabaev, If it was useful for you, accept my answer please

Answer (score 3):

try this after the last slash `\w+(-\w+)+` to match hyphenated words. It could be `'http://<store_url:\w+>.example.com/<product_name:\w+(-\w+)+>'` Let me know if it worked